# Airflow scheduler marked deleted DAG as active

Tags: airflow

I made some changes to my DAG process, renamed and ran airflow webserver and scheduler. The new and old DAGs show. The new DAG is inactive while the old DAG is active. Old DAG shows message:

`This DAG isn't available in the web server's DAG BAG object. It shows up in this list because the scheduler marked it as active in the metadata database`.

I did `airflow initdb` before running webserver and scheduler but still no changes, its still shows up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

Change the settings in airflow.cfg file:

```
# Are DAGs paused by default at creation
dags_are_paused_at_creation = False
```

and after that run below command:

```
airflow resetdb
```

You should now be able to view correct list of DAGs

Comment: be careful, I run airflow resetdb and lost all setup connections